# How to apply image texture and material color together?

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine, uv, uv-image-editor

Is it possible to apply both material color and image texture together? how?

Comment: Are you asking if Blender can blend a flat color and an image texture? Or do you mean that a surface will have part of flat color and part of image? Or what else? Anyway the answer is yes! Just explain better what you're looking for and which render engine are you using (Cycles, Blender Internal or else).

Comment: blend a flat color and an image texture in blender game engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the color of the cilinder is set to green, the applied devil texture has an influence below 1.0 (i.e. 0.793). The geometry normal slider controls the 3D bump effect of the texture.
In the bottom part of the influence tab you can choose the blend mode of the texture (i.e. I leaved it on the default value: "mix").

[image]